# gmail smtp problem

Tags: smtp, gmail, zend-mail

I am using gmail smtp to send emails from my website, but i noticed that some emails are dropped. I use Zend_Mail. Everything works as it supposed to for most of the emails, but if an email's subject/body is somewhat questionable, then it might not be sent. For example:

If I try to send emails like this:

Subject (asdjkasdf kasdjf kdfasdjfksdf) and Body (askdjf askjf asdf)

OR

Subject (SUBJECT) and Body (BODY)

Then gmail smtp will not do it. Zend_Mail returns true however.

Is there a spam filter or something that blocks such emails? What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SMTP returns no error, then your emails has been effectively SENT.

I bet the problem is that you don't see it in your inbox, that could be because it's marked as spam before that happens.